# How can I change a variable on an Angular directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, components

I'm trying to create a simple toggle for an HTML tooltip element within the HTML of an Angular directive. I am defining the attribute in the component, and I have verified it is being passed to the directive, but no matter what I try in the HTML, it doesn't modify the attribute's value.

Here's my component:

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges} from '@angular/core';
import { Utils } from './utils';
@Component({
  selector: 'm-chart',
  templateUrl: './m.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./s-chart.scss']
})
export class MembersChartComponent implements OnChanges {
  constructor (private utils: Utils) {}
  @Input() membersData:any;
  @Input() infoModalOpen:boolean;
}
```

Here's the parent template html:

```
<div class="row no-margin">
      <m-chart *ngIf="summaryData && summaryData.members" 
      [mData]="summaryData.members" infoModalOpen="false"></m-chart>
</div>
```

And here's the HTML for the directive:

```
<div class="row">
  <div ng-mouseover="infoModalOpen = !infoModalOpen" ng-mouseleave="infoModalOpen = !infoModalOpen" class="trigger">|</div>
  <div ng-show="infoModalOpen">Tooltip content here</div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to write functions as follows:

```
$scope.hoverIn = function(){
  this.hoverEdit = true;
};

$scope.hoverOut = function(){
    this.hoverEdit = false;
};
```

then change your html code as follows:

`<div ng-mouseover="hoverIn()" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()" class="trigger">|</div>`

please let me know if this works or not!

good luck

Comment: Where would you put those functions?

Comment: in your class  MembersChartComponent after the boolean

Comment: Thanks Abdullah - I ended up using css instead - changing the visibility of the element.